# Maple 2017 startup gui window “hangs” when I try to open it

Tags: maple

I just had maple downloaded and the command prompt and classic worksheet seem to work but when I try to use the desktop app maplew.exe the initial loading image comes up but then nothing happens. I then have to use the task manager to close it. I have tried running as an administrator among other things.  I am completely unsure how to fix this. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thanks

Comment: I have had issues with opening Maple before. This does seem more like a support question than a StackExchange question but perhaps if you supply more information we can find a way to fix it. What operating system are you on? What Maple version? Are there no error messages? Try to be specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all. I was able to email maple and I got a fast response. Maybe it can help someone in the future...

> Your security software might be scanning Maple. If you can’t add Maple
>   to the list of exceptions, please try temporarily disabling it.
>
> If that doesn’t help, please check the Details tab of your Task
>   Manager for jogamp-based processes. If terminating them allows Maple
>   to finish loading, please use the attached launch script; just save it
>   as a batch file.
>
> If that doesn’t help either, please try enabling the jaccess line in
>   `C:\Program Files\Maple 2017\bin.X86_64_WINDOWS\launch.ini` by removing
>   the `#` and `space` in front. If you have issues saving the file, please
>   move it to the desktop first, make and save the change, then move it
>   back to the bin folder.
>
> If that doesn’t help either, please enable the `maxheap` line in the
>   file above, and increase the value of `700`. `2048` is usually a good
>   value to try, but if your system has more memory, a higher value can
>   be used.
>
> If that doesn’t help either, please try adding `showconsole=true` to the
>   end of the file.
>
> File:
>
> ```
> if not "%minimized%"=="" goto :minimized set minimized=true
>
> start /min cmd /C "%~dpnx0" goto :EOF :minimized
>
> start "Maple 2017" "C:\Program Files\Maple
> 2017\bin.X86_64_WINDOWS\maplew.exe"
>
> :: Kill any jogamp_exe_tst processes than are spawned timeout 5 > NUL
> taskkill /F /IM jogamp_exe* timeout 5 > NUL taskkill /F /IM
> jogamp_exe* timeout 5 > NUL taskkill /F /IM jogamp_exe* timeout 5 >
> NUL taskkill /F /IM jogamp_exe* timeout 5 > NUL taskkill /F /IM
> jogamp_exe*
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The last part of the anwer above helped me. In the Task Manager i could see `jogamp_exeXXX` being started. Repeadedly killing it allowed Maple to start.

To clarify the answer above: create a `maple.cmd` file on your desktop. Then paste this into the file:

`start "Maple 2018" "C:\Program Files\Maple 2018\bin.win\maplew.exe"
timeout 5 > NUL
taskkill /F /IM jogamp_exe*
timeout 5 > NUL
taskkill /F /IM jogamp_exe* 
timeout 5 > NUL
taskkill /F /IM jogamp_exe* 
timeout 5 > NUL
taskkill /F /IM jogamp_exe* 
timeout 5 > NUL
taskkill /F /IM jogamp_exe*
timeout 5 > NUL
taskkill /F /IM jogamp_exe*
timeout 5 > NUL
taskkill /F /IM jogamp_exe*
timeout 5 > NUL
taskkill /F /IM jogamp_exe*`